# How to refresh data of parent in child component using function components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have trouble with updating data of a parent component inside of a child component.
I'm using React 18.2.0 with functional components.

To provide a basic code example for my problem:

**Parent.js**

```
export default function Parent() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([]);
    const [items, setItems] = useState("");
    const [size, setSize] = useState(2);

    useEffect(() => {
        refresh();
    }, [size]);

    function refresh() {
        let newStuff = Array(size).fill().map((_, index) => {
            return <Child key={index} counter={counter} items={items} setItems={setItems}/>;
        });

        setStuff(newStuff);
    }
}
...
```

**Child.js**

```
export default function Child({counter, items, setItems}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        refresh();
    }, [counter]);

    function refresh() {
        setItems(items + "test");
    }
}
```

So to explain it in a basic way: I have **parent** who has a counter, a string and an array as useState. The array "stuff" has many child components in one layer, the string "items" is here to be edited from the different child components.

The plan is to manually (e.g. through a button click) increment "counter", so that the useEffect in **all** child components fires and thus items should be edited.

But the problem is that the useEffect in the child component does not register that "counter" is incremented even though it is a useState variable.

So how can I go about this? I have one parent component which has a dataset which is modified by many child components in which lie in the parent component.

What am I missing? Do I have to use some other react functionalities (e.g. useRef, useContext or something)?

Comment: It isn't right to have a list of React components in an array that's a state.

Comment: Okay, but the list of child components needs to get rebuild depending on a different state in my code. How can I make this then?

Comment: Can you edit your question so we see `Parent` and `Child` entirely?

Comment: I edited it so that my previous comment is shown in the code through "size". Other than that, this is all the important code. My button handlers which change "counter" and "size" work fine.